# App.use access static file via url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a doubt about the `app.use` on Node.js.

Basically I have a form on a html file called index.html, and I want to serve the file via the app.use, like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

The `index.html` file is on my public file, but i get an error saying that it cant get the `index.html` file, with the `app.use` like I did, can't I access the `index.html` file via url like this: `localhost:portNumber/index.html`

**full code**

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.listen(3000,function(){

    app.get("/listUsers",function(req,res){

    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json","utf8",function(err,data){
        res.json(JSON.parse(data));
    });

    app.post('/addUser',function(req,res){
        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json",'utf8',function(err,data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var result = "{}";
            response = {
                        name:req.body.name,
                        password:req.body.password,
                        profession:req.body.profession,
                        id:req.body.id

            };

            data.users.push(response);
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json",JSON.stringify(data),'utf8');
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
});
```

})

Comment: Aren't you supposed to configure all of the `app.use` bits (and routes) _before_ you call `app.listen()`?

Comment: you are right i just moved it down and forgot to move it up xD, i edit

Comment: Have you tried using `path.join`? I believe your path might be invalid otherwise: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`